# How to import using fread from data.table

Tags: r, csv, data.table

I´m trying to import this kind of csv

```
"a";"b"
11092740;0
8978056137;0
```

using data.table fread command, but when I use it, I have wrong import values:

```
data<-fread(data.csv,sep=";")
data
               a b
1: 5.480542e-317 0
2: 4.435749e-314 0
```

How can I do to import them properly?

Thanks!

Comment: whats wrong? it seems right

Comment: are you sure your file name is saved under the variable name "data.csv"? shouldnt it read data<-fread("data.csv",sep=";") (notice the quotes)

Comment: I have solved installing and using bit64 CRAN package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, installing and using bit64 library from CRAN

```
install.packages("bit64")
library(bit64)
```